# Firebase Analytics Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64: "_OBJC_CLASS_$_FIRAnalytics"

Tags: ios, objective-c

After updating Firebase to 7.6.0 via cocoapods I get the following link error, but only when targeting the simulator.  Everything builds fine when targeting a device.

```
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_FIRAnalytics", referenced from:
      objc-class-ref in MainTabBarController.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
```

I have tried just about everything that stack overflow recommends for this error without any luck.  I have searched throughout the project for any reference to x86_64 vs arm to try and understand why one will link and the other wont.  Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: I am also getting similar error.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I finally solved this by clearing out the Framework Search Paths under the project’s Build Settings.  See: https://github.com/firebase/firebase-ios-sdk/issues/7614#issuecomment-786827116

Answer (score 0):

You might need to set this as a static library in your pod file

```
post_install do |installer|
installer.pods_project.targets.each do |target|
    target.build_configurations.each do |config|
        if  target.name == 'FirebaseAnalytics'
            config.build_settings['MACH_O_TYPE'] = 'staticlib'
        end
    end
end 
end
```

Answer (score 0):

I was using @awesome-cordova-plugins/firebase-analytics in a Capacitor app and when I upgraded from version 2 to 3 of Capacitor I started to get this error about *OBJC_CLASS*$_FIRAnalytics. I spent over half the day trying everything out there including the stuff here. Nothing worked and so I finally gave up and went for a different plugin. I switched over to [@capacitor-community/firebase-analytics](https://github.com/capacitor-community/firebase-analytics) and it eliminated the problem.

I don't think I had to change anything on the iOS side, but I had to make some minor changes to the js in my typescript files.