# Build error in ionic capacitor iOS app ‘Firebase.h’ not found

Tags: ios, ionic-framework, mobile, build, capacitor

I'm new to cross platform and mobile dev in general. I am using ionic6 with Angular and Capacitor3.
I am trying to make an app that uses push notifications (with Firebase). I had managed to compile my iOS app once, but on my 2nd attempt it didn't work although I hadn't changed anything.
I have followed  this documentation
https://capacitorjs.com/docs/guides/push-notifications-firebase
As well as this tutorial (I've copied the code from the doc as the tutorial is a little old)
https://devdactic.com/push-notifications-ionic-capacitor/

When I build my app, i get this error :

> /Users/usr/Documents/my-app/ios/capacitor-cordova-ios-plugins/sources/CordovaPluginFcmWithDependecyUpdated/FCMPlugin.m:8:9: 'Firebase.h' file not found with  include; use "quotes" instead"

If I change #import <Firebase.h> into #import "Firebase.h" as suggested, then I get his error :

> /Users/usr/Documents/my-app/ios/capacitor-cordova-ios-plugins/sources/CordovaPluginFcmWithDependecyUpdated/AppDelegate+FCMPlugin.m:215:7: Use of undeclared identifier 'FIRInstanceID'

[FIRInstanceID_error_image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0cxMA.png)

I read somewhere that I only need to comment it since it's deprecated. Which leads me to this error :

> Undefined symbol: *OBJC_CLASS*$_FIRAnalytics

[FIRAnalytics_error_image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rQ7dM.png)

I've tried almost everything I could find online but nothing works. I've been stuck here for a week now.
Please let me know if you have any leads or if you need more information (preferably how to get it since I'm still new to this, I may not know how to)

Thank you very much in advance !

Comment: Have a look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66327173/firebase-analytics-undefined-symbols-for-architecture-x86-64-objc-class-fir

Comment: Thank you ver  much for you reply
I actually had checked that link already, my search path is clear but I'm still getting the error. when I try @capacitor-community/firebase-analytics it says that other plugins depend on it.
I've managed to build my app by : 
- commenting the sign causing the 1st error
- replacing  Googleservice-Info.plist in my ios/capacitor-cordova-ios-plugins/resources/ by the same file from ios/App/App
These changes were done on node_module cuz otherwise the build will override my changes.
I'll try the plugin lead again cuz my temp solution doesn't look too pretty

Comment: You could also give [`@capacitor-firebase`](https://github.com/capawesome-team/capacitor-firebase) a try, which provides a consistent versioning across all Firebase SDKs.